# Extract first 2 sentences using PHP

Tags: strpos

I came up with this code which extracts the first sentence from a text. However I need to extract the first 2 sentences and I can't figure out what to do. Any ideas?

```
$input = get_field('fl_description');

$pos = strpos($input, '.' , 1);
$output = substr($input, 0, $pos+1);

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$input = get_field('fl_description');
$pos = strpos($input, '.' , 1); 
$pos = strpos($input, '.' , $pos+1); 
$output = substr($input, 0, $pos+1);
echo $output; '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using explode method with delimeter ".". Setting the limit to 2, will create array containing 2 elements, with the first 2 sentences.

> $arrayOfSentences = explode ('.' , $input ,2 );
>
> echo $arrayOfSentences[0]+" "+$arrayOfSentences[1];

More on explode method: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.explode.php